# Quickest way to query nested collection / document data

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

My Flutter application will have to reference multiple collections in Fire store on a single page based on user input.  I have two collections in my Fire Store DB at the moment.  Each collection has its own data detailed below.

**Collection 1**

- Contains documents that store the following fields **(A, B, C)**

**Collection 2**

- Contains docs with nested collections, with nested docs, and those docs contain fields **(C, D, E)**
- The **(C)** field is a postID stored in Collection 1, so there is a connection between specific document fields if needed

Is there a way to quickly reference each field individually without having to use a stream builder each time?  If not, should I even be using Fire Store as my main database for this app plan?